# Failed to create startup registy entry to run batch command

Tags: windows, batch-file, startup, regedit

I am trying to optimize W7 UI for a laptop with a wide screen by putting the taskbar on the left and making it thin. I managed this a couple of ways the most successfully by restarting UxSms with [Task Scheduler](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-administrator-mode-shortcuts-without-uac-prompts-in-windows-vista/) and a batch file. [This source](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/regedit.php) is what gave me the idea that I could run the batch with Regedit.

**The actual question** I would like to answer is why the .reg I made merged without error, but didn't create a key that I could find or seem to run anything when the previously mentioned "This source" seems to suggest that it should work. Obviously I made a mistake, but would really like to understand it.

Name of file: ThinTask.reg

```
    REGEDIT4

    ; @ECHO OFF
    ; CLS
    ; REGEDIT.EXE /S "%~f0"
    ; net stop "UxSms"
    ; net start "UxSms"
    ; EXIT

    [HKEY_CURRENT_USERSOFTWAREMicrosoftWindowsCurrentVersionRun] "ThinTask"="Succeeded"
```

The batch I want to run is really just:

```
    net stop "UxSms"
    net start "UxSms"
```

Any ideas on where I went wrong? Thank you for your time any comments, suggestions, or resources are most welcome.

Comment: Forget registry manipulations. If your batch works, simply move it to user's [Startup folder](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7). (Or create a shortcut there as above link describes).

Comment: The lines of `ThinTask.reg` are not valid for Regedit. And the string value created in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` with name `ThinTask` does not specify the name of executable with full path to run. So the lines of `ThinTask.reg` posted here do not make any sense at all.

Comment: @JosefZ that was the first thing I tried as stated in my post. When attempting this via start menu it would not work, so I physically navigated to the folder and tried both the script it's self and an admin shortcut. No dice regardless of what I tried with that. Looking outside regedit, per your advice, did get me to a solution using the task scheduler. I will add the information to my original post, but would still like to know more about my failure in working with regedit.

Comment: Passed over, sorry. Create a restore point in `System properties`. Then launch `regedit`, find out the `Run` key and export it to see _how-to_ :)

Comment: @Mofi you are right that the batch commands are not valid for Regedit. According to the link "this" in my post however you can work around this using ; to comment out lines in Regedit while still running them as batch. As for the path the line starting "; Regedit.exe ..." should cover that without having to hard code it. I can make an exe out of it using the resource I am adding about Task Scheduler, so I will try that as well. Obviously I did do something wrong and ideally that is what I would like to fix.

Comment: To add a single value to HKEY_CURRENT_USER it is better to use `reg.exe add` instead of `regedit.exe`. Run in a command prompt window `reg.exe add /?` for help on syntax of this command. Adding a single value to HKEY_CURRENT_USER with `reg.exe` does not require administrator privileges while doing the same with `regedit.exe` and a *.reg file requires administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0):

My dumb mistake. Suppose to save it as a .bac not .reg. No wonder the registry didn't know what to do if I'm trying to run it that way and the whole thing is commented out.